# How to visualize data with Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I am making application for data visualization, using Highcharts and JQuery. The program has to get some data from array and make another array, using empty fields for entering from.. to.. data. This is my code:

```
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<center>
    <form>
        <p>First value:</p>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first">
        <br/>Last value:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="secondname" id="second">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</center>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSubmit').on("click", function() {

            var array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];

            var newArray = [];
            var firstVal = $('#first').val();
            var lastVal = $('#second').val();

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] >= firstVal && array[i] <= lastVal) {
                    newArray.push(array[i]);
                }
         else {
newArray.push(null);
}
            }
 for (var i=0; i<newArray.length;i++) {
  $('#container').highcharts({
title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [ ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Array_no'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' '
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'ArrayNo',
        data: newArray
    }, ]
});
};

  });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Wrote like that, the program works, but when i enter a bigger data. For example i change the variable `var array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];` with a bigger array:

```
var array = ${first};
```

which contains more then 40 000 points, the chart doesn't appear... How to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure, that highchart can handle 40 000 points? That's an really big javascript array.

Comment: I think so. If i don't have the jQuery function for choosing from one value to another and i visualize the whole array of 40 000, there is no problem with Highcharts.

Comment: It could be bad data?  One invalid char could wreck the processing.  I'd use a JS debugger to see what errors you get.

Comment: Thanks, but the data is ok. There aren't any invalid chars...

Comment: Have you tried to set [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) param as 0?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change. It's so slow... the chart even doesn't appear.

Comment: In case when this is line chart, you can you [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) or [boost](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/175-highcharts-performance-boost) module